# Use of $rootScope and app.constant in AngularJs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I need to set my ralis api-url in angularJs Front-end application which is same for entire application which one is the best solution currently i am using constant.

```
var app = angular.module('enbakeCRM',[]);

app.constant('apiUrl', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

> **calling inside the controller same as services**

```
app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope,apiUrl) {
            console.log(apiUrl);
    });
```

Comment: that looks fine to me. Personally I created a service, but guess a constant makes more sense. Here is an article on the subject: http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/06/angularjs-best-practices-001-constants/.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: question is about , Constant in angular for some global configuration for  backed, thank you Jax , your article is very use full. Sorry for my bad English :)